# How to obtain the amplitude for the leptonic pion decay?

Tags: standard-model, feynman-diagrams, effective-field-theory, pions

Consider the leptonic decay of the pion
$$\pi^{+}\rightarrow l^{+}\nu_{l}$$
In my notes there's written that in order to compute the associated rate we can use the effective Lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L}^{\pi\rightarrow l\nu_{l}}=-\frac{G_{F}}{\sqrt{2}}V^{*}_{ud}[\bar{d}\gamma_{\mu}(1-\gamma^{5})u][\bar{\nu}_{l}\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma^{5})l]$$
This apparently means that the amplitude is just
$$\mathcal{M}(\pi\rightarrow l\nu_{l})=-i\frac{G_{F}}{\sqrt{2}}V^{*}_{ud}\langle0|\bar{d}\gamma_{\mu}(1-\gamma^{5})u|\pi(p_{\pi})\rangle\bar{u}(k')\gamma^{\nu}(1-\gamma^{5})v(k)$$
This is quite confusing to me, I've always used Feynman rules to get the amplitudes in momentum space so why we couldn't write simply something like
$$\mathcal{M}(\pi\rightarrow l\nu_{l})=-i\frac{G_{F}}{\sqrt{2}}V^{*}_{ud}\bar{v}_{u}(p)\gamma_{\mu}(1-\gamma^{5})u_{d}(k)\times\bar{u}(k')\gamma^{\nu}(1-\gamma^{5})v(k)$$
but instead we have to keep the matrix element? This could be a very stupid question but I'm still new to SM. I know that $\pi$ is a bounded state so maybe this changes things, but how can you reach that conclusion?

Comment: You are completely cool with the intermediate amplitude $\pi^+\to \bar d u$, represented by the matrix element, right? Your effective Lagrangian connects quarks to leptons, but you need to resolve the hadron into quarks.

Comment: Mm could you please argue that with more details? I don't get your point...Are u saying that the total amplitude is the product of the probability of the $\pi^{+}\rightarrow \bar{d}u$ and $\bar{d}u\rightarrow l\nu_{l}$ processes? My confusion is that the process is represented with a simple tree level Feynman diagram, so why should I keep the matrix element written in that way? Of course I could start with the S matrix etc... but I'd like to have a more intuitive answer

Comment: "A simple tree level Feynman diagram"?? Are you referring to the 4-fermion vertex, or the implicit pion-2-lepton one resulting from it? You have essentially written *two*, not one, effective lagrangians, related in the obvious way. Go back to your text (M Schwartz, by the sound of it).

Comment: Yes I mean the 4-fermion vertex, with the pions represented as their "sum" as initial state. My notes don't describe how to treat those cases, I'm going to check if the Schwartz says anything. Thank you

Comment: I tried starting from the matrix element : $S_{fi}=-\frac{G_{F}}{\sqrt{2}}<k,k'|∫ d^{4}x:[\bar{d}\gamma_{\mu}(1-\gamma^{5})u][\bar{\nu}_{l}\gamma^{\mu}(1-\gamma^{5})l]:|\pi(p_{\pi}))>+\mathcal{O}(G_{F}^{2})$ and I'm digging into calculations, does it make sense to you?

Comment: I got the right result, but I used a completeness relation $|0><0|=\mathbb{1}$ which I don't know if It makes sense

Comment: Yes, vacuum dominance.